# Picasso проблемы с кешированием и нехваткой памяти

Tags: java, android

Использую библиотеку Picasso. И столкнулся с проблемами и ошибками:

> E/Bitmap﹕ createBitmap error!

Пример кода:

```
Picasso
    .with(this)
    .load(object.getImages([1])
    .error(R.drawable.video_cap)
    .into(exVideo);
```

Поначалу всё работает, но позже (когда смотрю по второму кругу) выходит краш "Out of memory". Я использовал методы `fit()` и `resize()` - приложение работает дольше, но заканчивается одинаково.

Обработав ошибку:

```
try {                 
    Picasso.with(this)
        .load(object.getImages([1])
        .error(R.drawable.video_cap)
        .into(exVideo);
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {}
```

приложение больше не падает. Но фотографии больше не загружаются и приложение начинает тормозить. Как я понимаю, `Picasso` занял всю оперативную память и больше нет места под новые фотографии.

Мне надо как-то стереть фотографии из оперативной памяти, чтоб отобразить новые.

Использование `memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`, не подойдёт. Я кеширую фотки на SD карту прописав этот код в классе `Application`:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
Picasso built = builder.build();
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

Я храню ссылки на фотки в базе, и `Picasso` потом успешно их загружает.

Итого у меня 3 вопроса:

1. как освободить место в оперативной памяти под новые фотки
2. как кешировать на SD карту только нужные фотки, а не все
3. как обработать ошибку "E/Bitmap﹕ createBitmap error!"

По нажатию на кнопку я загружаю новые изображения

```
if (object.getImages().length > 1) {
        try {
            Log.e("test", "load picasso 1");
            Picasso.with(this).load(object.getImages()[1]).fit().tag("tag1").error(R.drawable.video_cap).into(exVideo);
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.e("test", "error 1" + e);
            Picasso.with(this).load(object.getImages()[1]).fit().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(exVideo);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("test", "error 11" + e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Приложите код, где именно Вы вызываете подгрузку изображений

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать вместо 
 `.into(exVideo);`
использовать следующий код, который масштабирует изображение до его отображения:

```
.into(new Target() {
     @Override
     public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         int targetWidth = exVideo.getWidth();
         float ratio = (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
         float heightFloat = ((float) targetWidth) * ratio;

         final android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams
                 = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.image.getLayoutParams();

         layoutParams.height = (int) heightFloat;
         layoutParams.width = (int) targetWidth;
         holder.image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
         holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
     }
});
```